# VBA Hide/Unhide duplicate rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set that looks like this

ID |  Cost  |  Name
   001    |   10   |    Bicycle
   002    |   05   |    Tricycle
   001    |   10   |    Bicycle
   001    |   10   | Bicycle
   002 | 05 | Tricycle
003 | 15 | Motorcycle
003 | 15 | Motorcycle

Currently, I need to hide the rows which are duplicated, keeping only one set of the original row, like so.

ID | Cost | Name
001 | 10 | Bicycle
002 | 05 | Tricycle
003 | 15 | Motorcycle

The code that I have found can only delete the duplicates, but for completeness, I cannot have them deleted, I need to only hide them for reporting, and be able to unhide the rows again with a click of a button.

My current codes look like this

```
Private Sub removeDuplicates()

' Get last row
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C" & LR).removeDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you !!
I'm sorry if I'm not providing enough information.
PS: I started coding VBA for about a week before.

Comment: Use the Filter function to remove duplicates (temporarily or permanently). https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2. If you feel you must have VBA, use the macro recorder to start you off.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me towards advanced filtering, I got exactly what I needed !